# Integrate Babel into Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, babeljs

I have built an angular website working perfectly fine in chrome, but it is failing in IE because of ES6

I am running angular using cdn with a node server which is only used for serving the webpage, no code is there other than listening to port.

I want to add babel into that, but all the examples I am finding are for server code or using gulp or webpack. Is there any way to directly integrate babel for my purpose or I definitely need to have webpack\gulp configured.

[Included the directory structure of the code, all the files are getting linked in index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq6QL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since babel changes your javascript I don't think you can include it in your html page you need to have it in a grunt or such pipeline so the javascript is transformed and then the transformed javascript is served:

```
gulp.task('build', [], function () {
    return gulp.src('./app/index.html')
        .pipe(preprocess({context: production_config.context}))
        .pipe(babel({ presets: ['env'] }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build');
    });
```

Then serve "build" instead of "app"

Maybe there's a more dynamic way